# ansible undefined variable in task

Tags: ansible

I use molecule to test ansible role. Task is copy template using variable.
ansible/task/main.yml

```
---
- name: copy manifest billing
  template:
    src: templates/service.j2
    dest: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      "{{ services }}"
```

ansible/vars/main.yml

```
services:
  - billing
  - cart
  - checkout
```

When i run "molecule converge" I get error

```
TASK [ansible : copy manifest billing] *****************************************
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user/ansible/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: copy manifest billing\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q: **"*The error was: 'item' is undefined*"**

A: The indentation is wrong. `with_items` is not a parameter of the module. It's the directive to loop the module. Correct syntax is

```yaml
    ---
    - name: copy manifest billing
      template:
        src: templates/service.j2
        dest: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        "{{ services }}"
```

---

Notes

- It is not necessary to nest the variable. [Better syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items) is

```yaml
    with_items: "{{ services }}"
```

- With the release of Ansible 2.5, the recommended way to perform loops is the use of the new [loop keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) instead of with_X style loop

```yaml
    loop: "{{ services }}"
```

- Inconsistent results of the command `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --check`. The command does NOT complain `"Invalid options for template: with_items"`! But, for example, with the module `debug` the checking works as expected

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
        with_items: "{{ services }}"
```

```sh
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid options for debug: with_items"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should [include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html) variables from file:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include_vars: 
     file: ansible/vars/main.yml
  - name: copy manifest billing
    template:
      src: templates/service.j2
      dest: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      "{{ services }}"
```

Or [explicitly add vars_files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files)

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - ansible/vars/main.yml
  tasks:   
  - name: copy manifest billing
    template:
      src: templates/service.j2
      dest: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      "{{ services }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answers before, it is an indentation problem.

Try the [Ansible Template tester](https://ansible.sivel.net/test/). It is very useful when it comes to checking your Ansible templates before adding them to your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you.
I use one j2 template for multiple config.
I need take every item in services items in same config file name.
Part of my templates/service.j2

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ common.fullname }}-{% for item in services %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}"
```

But it's not work right for me.
I should get one of the list values in the file of the same name and the next value from the list in the corresponding file name.
Now it take

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "hf-billingcartcheckout"
```